# Testing the Patch odata webapi method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I need to test the following Patch method in my odata controller from my test project.

```
[ValidateModel]
        [AcceptVerbs("PATCH", "MERGE")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Patch([FromODataUri] int key, Delta<User> patch)
        {
            var user = await db.Users.FindAsync(key);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            patch.Patch(user);

            Validate(user);

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            try
            {
                db.Entry(user).Property(p => p.UserType).IsModified = false;
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!UserExists(key))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                throw;
            }

            return Updated(user);
        }
```

The code in the test project is as follows. Could someone tell me how do I pass value to the Delta parameter. Currently I am getting compilation errors at line  controller.Patch(1,   user);.

```
[TestMethod]
        public void TestPatch()
        {
            // Arrange
            var controller = new UsersController();

            var user = new User();
            user.Id = 1;
            user.Lastname = "Johanson";
            // Act
            controller.Patch(1,  <System.Web.OData.Delta> user);

            // Assert
        }
```

Comment: What is the compilation error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var delta = new Delta<User>(typeof(User));
delta.TrySetPropertyValue("Id", 1);
delta.TrySetPropertyValue("Lastname", "Johanson");
```

I don't know if there are any helpers to make that easier

Comment: How would you pass that to controller.Patch

Comment: controller.Patch(1, delta);

Comment: I tried to apply the same concept - using Guid Key  but get the following message:  System.Not ImplementedException

Answer (score 5):

You can also declare the delta using the dynamic keyword and set the properties directly:

```
dynamic delta = new Delta<User>();
delta.Id = 1;
delta.Lastname = "Johanson";
```

Answer (score 3):

@yenta's answer is perfectly fine, but if you can, also consider using the `nameof` (since C# 6.0)

```
var delta = new Delta<User>(typeof(User));
delta.TrySetPropertyValue(nameof(User.Id), 1);
delta.TrySetPropertyValue(nameof(User.Lastname), "Johanson");
```